# How to I use the elasticsearch python api to get an overview of all snapshots?

Tags: python, api, elasticsearch, get

I'm using the elasticsearch python api to communicate with my elasticsearch database. How can I make a specific GET request to get an overview of all the snapshots that have been created?

The Kibana command for this would be:  `GET /_snapshot/my_backup/_all`.

It seems the `Elasticsearch.get()` function is only suited to retrieve documents.

I would rather not use the Requests module.

The snapshot helper functions I found only have the option to get an overview of snapshots that are currently running.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.snapshot.get_repository('my_backup') # configuration information
es.snapshot.status('my_backup') # currently running snapshots
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally realized you can use the `_all` keyword when needing all snapshots, in the following way:

`all_snapshots = es.snapshot.get(repository = 'my_backup', snapshot = '_all')`

Answer (score 1):

Just adding one of my own as this got me in the right path.
If you need to get the general snapshot status i.e if a snapshot is being run:

```
es_session.snapshot.status('_all')
```